# Why is Bootstrap navigation extending below the screen in landscape mode of phone?

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, screen

I made a website http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/ Now when I open this website in chrome browser in computer and uses device toolbar to mimic landscape mode of mobile the navigation menu works properly. Bootstrap decreases the height of navigation containing div and allows scrolling. IN the developer tools bootstrap uses following media query

```
@media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

But when I open my website on actual mobile phone(android) in landscape mode then no `max-height: 200px` is applied and the last two navigation items extnd below mobile screen; making them completely inaccessible. So my question is:

> Why is Bootstrap navigation extending below the screen in landscape mode of phone?

Comment: Works perfectly on my phone ( Android too). Are you sure your browser isn't set to open the Desktop version instead of the mobile one?

Comment: @MarinNedea There is a `request desktop site` option. But it is unchecked.

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem, but without success. Maybe it's some compatibility issue with your phone browser.

Comment: @MarinNedea I tried it now on another android phone(asus) and the problem still pertains. I'll try to post it's snapshot or maybe a video recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that nowadays the a usual 5 inches mobile has height more than 600 logical pixels. But the bootstrap media query applies for less than 420 logical pixel height, cf `@media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)`. So I need to use a custom media query in my style.css file as:

```
@media (max-device-height: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

My navbar-header is 60px tall and navbar is 310px tall So I need any media query with max-width greater than or equal to 370px.